# why can one not modify elemnts in an enhanced for loop?

Tags: java

I wrote the following piece of code:

```
int[][] board = new int[width][height];
        for(int[] Element : board){
            for(int element : Element){
                element = randomInt(-1, 9);
            }
        }
```

randomInt is a method that returns an integer between the 2 parameter values.

What I wanted was a 2-dimensional array with random values in the corresponding interval.

I thought I was doing it elegantly by using the enhanced for-loop, but I always got 0s.
I doublechecked it with the debugger, and yes, element remains at its default value (i.e. 0).

My intuition is that the enhanced for-loop is here not appropriate.
Why?

Comment: `element` is just a variable. It's just declared in a slightly different way than a normal variable, e.g. `board`. At the start of every iteration of the loop, the loop will copy the value (or reference) of the next item into that variable. So all you are doing with `randomInt` is reassigning a new value to that variable for the remainder of that scope (the closing `}`). In your case, doing so is pointless, because it will be immediately overwritten by the next iteration of the loop.

Comment: Instead, you can use 2 normal for-loops with indices. Then assign with `board[i][j] = randomInt(-1, 9)`

Comment: Worth noting, a clever IDE will be able to detect this and warn you about it. IntelliJ gives me the warning "*The value randomInt(-1, 9) assigned to 'element' is never used*". If you're using an IDE (or worse, a text editor) that does not warn you about these kind of problems, do yourself a favour and switch now. There is really no reason not to.